# Kubernetes network policy issue- pod selector does not work

Tags: kubernetes, networking

after 1 hours eye-soring investigation, I gave up and come here for help.

I am using GKE free account for my own poc:

here is the network policy yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: access-nginx
spec:
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      season: winter
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          abc: granted
```

and here is the pod yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
    season: winter
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: pod
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

after creating both items, I create a curl pod without any label and run:
`kubectl exec pod/curl -it -- curl 10.0.7.205`  
the IP address `10.0.7.205` is the IP address for the my-nginx pod.

If this works as I hoped for, I should NOT be able to see the reply from the my-NGINX pod. but unfortunately, the network policy does not seem to control the traffic at all for this pod.

anyone?

Comment: Did you manage to find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

By default network policies will allow all traffic. What you should do is configure default deny rule for ingress traffic:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-ingress
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/ for details.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I setup the deny default policy. but same problem. I am suspecting GKE may have weird behavior. Will try other place when I get may hands on it.